# unable to load native hadoop library in pycharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Not sure how to resolve this issue at Pycharm. Tried copying hadoop library to the file but still experiencing the same issue. I've made sure that I have the latest python and hadoop installed.

[image]

Comment: Please add details of your issue: info about your OS, involved software versions, errors if any.

Comment: This is a warning and won't prevent Spark from working. You need to run your Spark history server to see the actual issue